# Implode array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have implode code like this :

```
$date_condition = implode(" AND a.date = ",$date_interval);
```

That array looks like this :

```
$date_interval = Array('2017-01-24','2017-01-25','2017-01-26');
```

This is what I want to expected become an output :

```
$date_condition = "'2017-01-24' AND a.date = '2017-01-25' AND a.date = '2017-01-26' ";
```

But from my code that I was try I just get output like this :

```
$date_condition = "2017-01-24 AND a.date = 2017-01-25 AND a.date = 2017-01-26";
```

How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date_interval = Array('2017-01-24','2017-01-25','2017-01-26');
$date_condition ="'". implode("' AND a.date = '",$date_interval)."'";
echo $date_condition;
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/634c950d7e8b2a3b6ff901d5e796dbeb499f6112)

Answer (score 1):

Either change the array:

```
$date_interval = Array("'2017-01-24'","'2017-01-25'","'2017-01-26'");
```

Loop through it:

```
foreach($date_interval as $k => $v){
  $date_interval[$k] = "'$v'";
}
```

Create a function:

```
function quotate(array $list){
  foreach($list as $v){
    $ret[] = "'$v'";
  }

  return $ret;
}

$date_condition = implode(" AND a.date = ",quotate($date_interval));
```

Or do it by adding quotes to this `' AND a.date = '` string, but Suchit beat me to it.